# jquery-ui-autocomplete is not loaded with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, jquery-ui

when I load the default jquery-ui-autocomplete script from wordpress via

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete', '', array( 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position' ), '1.8.6' );
```

it is embedded, and all works fine, except the annoying notice message in debug mode:

> Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles
>   should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts,
>   admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks ...

The solution therefore is quite easy, only wrap the `wp_enqueue_script` call:

```
function add_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete', '', array( 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position' ), '1.8.6' ); //don't loads the autocomplete
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete'); //same as above
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

BUT these technique doesn't embeds the `jquery-ui-autocomplete script`, only the annoying message disappear. The only way the `jquery-ui-autocomplete` script is embed, is without wrapping it ...

Where is my error? According to the documentation in the codex it should be done by wrapping the call and simply call `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete');` inside.

BR,
mybecks

Comment: What version of WordPress? jquery-ui-autocomplete was added in 3.3 I think...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is not loading? I tried this(using WordPress 3.6-beta1):

```
function add_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

I got jQuery and jQuery migrate in the header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.9.1'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.1.1'></script>
```

And jQuery UI in the footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.menu.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
```

Do you have `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your theme? Have you tried it with a simple theme and all plugins deactivated?

Comment: wp_enqueue_scripts loads script for the front end
admin_enqueue_scripts loads scripts for back end

That was my Problem. Anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: yes, you didn't mention that you were working on the back end...

Answer (score 0):

In order to use wp_enqueue_scripts action and be called by WordPress, the function call wp_head() must be added before the ending  tag and the function wp_foot(); must be added before the ending body tag or

Comment: There is no function like `wp_foot`, it's called `wp_footer`